# Including a barcode into a longtable

Tags: longtable, barcodes

I would like to have a barcode in my longtable, but when I try to put one into it, I have the following error:

[image]

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{array,longtable}
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
  \font\myfont=cmr12 at 21pt
 \title{}
 \usepackage{layout}
 \usepackage[nomarginpar, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{plain}

\newcommand{\newPart}[1]{
\part*{#1}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}


\newcommand{\newSection}[1]{
\section*{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}}

 % pour afficher dans le "toc", des lignes en pointillées entre les chapitres des livres et leur numéro de page.
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

 % suppress page number in toc for parts
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\usepackage{sectsty}\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\underline}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{corrected}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38}
 \definecolor{error}{rgb}{0.8, 0.25, 0.33}
 \definecolor{no_change}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
 \setmainlanguage{french}
 \setotherlanguage{greek}
 \newfontfamily\greekfont{Arial}
\newcommand\Pheader{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.7pt}}

\usepackage{pageslts}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}
\makeatother
\let\oldtabular\tabular\renewcommand{\tabular}{\large\selectfont\oldtabular} 

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{gospelbook}
\setcounter{gospelbook}{1}
\newcommand{\mygospelbook}[1]
{\setcounter{gospelchapter}{1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}#1}

\newcommand{\agospelbook}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}\mygospelbook{#1}}

\newcounter{gospelchapter}
\newcommand{\mygospelchapter}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thegospelchapter}\LARGE\bfseries\thegospelchapter\refstepcounter{gospelchapter}}

 % for finals N
\newcommand{\finalN}[1]{\textoverline{#1~~}}
 \newcommand{\finalNedit}[3]{\color{#3}{\textoverline{\color{#2}{#1}~~} }}  


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
%\foreignlanguage{greek}{\tableofcontents}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
\newgeometry{margin=0.0in}
\clearpage

 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}

\Large
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\mygospelbook{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον}} \textbf{(\nospace{1:1})} } \\ \\ [-1em] 
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
&  & &  & \\ [-0.9em]
 \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{υιου αβρααμ αβρααμ εγεννηϲεν τον} & 3 & \textbf{2} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιϲαακ ιϲαακ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ια} & 9 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ιουδαν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου ιουδαϲ δε} & 2 & \textbf{3} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον φαρεϲ και τον ζαρα} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκ τηϲ θαμαρ φαρεϲ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζρωμ εζρωμ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 20 &  \\
& 21 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αραμ αραμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αμινα} & 5 & \textbf{4} \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαβ αμιναδαβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νααϲϲων νααϲϲων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαλμων ϲαλμων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{5} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον βοοζ εκ τηϲ ραχαβ βοοζ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ωβηδ εκ τηϲ ρουθ ωβηδ} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δε εγεννηϲεν τον ειεϲϲαι ιεϲϲαι δε} & 2 & \textbf{6} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον δαυειδ τον βαϲιλεα} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαυειδ δε ο βαϲιλευϲ εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲολομωντα εκ τηϲ του ουριου ϲολο} & 1 & \textbf{7} \\
& 1 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μων δε εγεννηϲεν τον ροβοαμ} & 5 &  \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ροβοαμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αβια αβι} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{α δε εγεννηϲεν τον αϲα αϲα δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{8} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ιωϲαφατ ιωϲαφατ δε} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον ιωραμ ιωραμ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον οζειαν οζειαϲ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{9} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωαθαμ ιωαθαμ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αχαζ αχαζ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζεκιαν εζεκιαϲ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{10} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον μαναϲϲη μαναϲηϲ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αμων αμων δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ιωϲιαν ιωϲιαϲ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 4 & \textbf{11} \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
% I TRY TO INSERT THE BARCODE HERE ------------
\fbox{
\parbox[b][1in]{1.5in} {
    \psbarcode{http://ntvmr.uni-muenster.de/community/modules/papyri/?zoom=11&left=5&top=-5&site=INTF&image=20032/0/10/10/2}{}{codablockf}
}}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{1:11})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιεχονιαν και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{επι τηϲ μετοικεϲιαϲ βαβυλωνοϲ} & 13 &  \\
\textbf{12} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μετα δε την μετοικεϲιαν βαβυλωνοϲ} & 5 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιεχονιαϲ εγεννηϲεν τον ϲαλαθιηλ} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲαλαθιηλ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ζορο} & 14 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βαβελ ζοροβαβελ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 3 & \textbf{13} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον αβιουδ αβιουδ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελιακιμ ελιακιμ δε εγεννη} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αζωρ αζωρ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{14} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαδδωκ ϲαδδωκ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον αχειν αχειν δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελιουδ ελιουδ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 3 & \textbf{15} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελεαζαρ ελεαζαρ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ματθαν ματθαν δε εγεννη} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιακωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{16} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωϲηφ τον ανδρα μαριαϲ} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εξ ηϲ εγεννηθη \textoverline{ιϲ} ο λεγομενοϲ \textoverline{χϲ}} & 15 &  \\
\textbf{17} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παϲαι ουν αι γενεαι απο αβρααμ ε} & 7 & \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ωϲ δαυειδ γενεαι δεκατεϲϲαρεϲ} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και απο δαυειδ εωϲ τηϲ μετοικε} & 16 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲιαϲ βαβυλωνοϲ γενεαι \textoverline{ιδ}} & 19 &  \\
& 20 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και απο τηϲ μετοικεϲιαϲ βαβυλω} & 24 &  \\
& 24 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νοϲ εωϲ του \textoverline{χυ} γενεαι \textoverline{ιδ}} & 29 &  \\
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του δε \textoverline{ιυ} η γενεϲειϲ ουτωϲ ην} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μνηϲτευθειϲηϲ γαρ τηϲ μητροϲ αυ} & 12 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του μαριαϲ τω ιωϲηφ πριν η ϲυνελ} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θειν αυτουϲ ευρεθη εν γαϲτρι εχου} & 23 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲα εκ \textoverline{πνϲ} αγιου} & 26 &  \\
\textbf{19} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιωϲηφ δε ο ανηρ αυτηϲ δικαιοϲ ων} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και μη θελων αυτην παραδιγματιϲαι} & 12 &  \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help : ) !

Comment: A small but complete example doument ([minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) would be really helpful here. Would you prepare one and include it in your question?

Comment: To get rid of the error message, add a `\\ `between teh barcode's box and the following `\newpage` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error message, add a `\\` between the barcode's box and the following `\newpage` command. - leandriis